# How to see sales per item every week for last year in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will show me how many units were sold each week for the last year.  I started by getting the numbers for the last year like so...

```
select i.[INV ITEM Ext ID],i.[INV ITEM Description], sum(d.[ar orderd qty]) as 'Total Units Sold'  
from [inv items] i  
join [ar order detail] d on (d.[ar orderd item id] = i.[INV ITEM Ext ID])  
join [ar order] o on (o.[AR ORDER Document #] = d.[AR ORDERD Document #])  
where o.[AR ORDER Document #] not like '%Ret%' and d.[ar orderd date] > '9/16/2013' and d.[AR ORDERD Qty] >= '0'  
group by i.[INV ITEM Ext ID], i.[INV ITEM Description]  
order by i.[INV ITEM Ext ID]
```

This returned all of the items that have been sold within the last year.  Now I need to show if those items sold that week or did not sell that week. This is the code I tried to run however it does not return all of the items that were in the above query just the items that sold.

```
select i.[INV ITEM Ext ID],i.[INV ITEM Description], sum(d.[ar orderd qty]) as 'Total Units Sold'  
from [inv items] i    
join [ar order detail] d on (d.[ar orderd item id] = i.[INV ITEM Ext ID])    
join [ar order] o on (o.[AR ORDER Document #] = d.[AR ORDERD Document #])    
where o.[AR ORDER Document #] not like '%Ret%' and d.[ar orderd date] between '9/16/2013' and '9/22/2013' and d.[AR ORDERD Qty] >= '0'    
group by i.[INV ITEM Ext ID], i.[INV ITEM Description]    
order by i.[INV ITEM Ext ID]
```

Is there a way I can run one query having my criteria in the sum statement? for example have the output be (inv item ext id) (inv item description) (total Units sold 9/16-9/22) (Total units sold 9/23-9/29) (Total Units sold 9/30- 10/6)...... I need to have the same products on all the querys so i can paste it into excel.

Comment: What database is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general name for this type of query is `pivot` or `cross-tab`. Conditional aggregation is a general purpose way of doing it, although many databases support other methods:

```
select
    i.[INV ITEM Ext ID],
    i.[INV ITEM Description],
    sum(d.[ar orderd qty]) as 'Total Units Sold',
    sum(case when
            d.[ar orderd date] >= '2013-09-16' and
            d.[ar orderd date] < '2013-09-23'
        then d.[ar orderd qty]
        else 0 end) as 'total Units sold 9/16-9/22',
    sum(case when
            d.[ar orderd date] >= '2013-09-23' and
            d.[ar orderd date] < '2013-09-30'
        then d.[ar orderd qty]
        else 0 end) as 'total Units sold 9/23-9/29'
from
    [inv items] i
        inner join
    [ar order detail] d
        on d.[ar orderd item id] = i.[INV ITEM Ext ID]
        inner join
    [ar order] o
        on o.[AR ORDER Document #] = d.[AR ORDERD Document #]
where
    o.[AR ORDER Document #] not like '%Ret%' and
    d.[ar orderd date] > '9/16/2013' and
    d.[AR ORDERD Qty] >= '0'
group by
    i.[INV ITEM Ext ID],
    i.[INV ITEM Description]
order by
    i.[INV ITEM Ext ID];
```

If you're using MS Access, you might need to change the `case` statements to use `IIF`.